# How can I add compiler warnings in CMake that exclude Protobuf files?

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, gcc-warning, proto

I'm adding warnings (and treating them as errors) to my C++ project which uses CMake for builds. Initially I used [target_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html). But as I've added more warnings I've found that they're being triggered by the generated protobuf files.

The build looks like this:

```
protobuf_generate_cpp(MYAPP_PROTO_SRCS MYAPP_PROTO_HDRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/myapp.proto)

set(MYAPP_SRCS ${MYAPP_PROTO_SRCS} myapp.cpp)

add_executable(myapp ${MYAPP_SRCS})

target_compile_options(myapp PRIVATE -Wall -Werror)
```

What I want to do is to be able to set warnings for all source files except the generated protobuf file (in this case `myapp.pb.cc`). Is there any standard way of doing this in CMake?

Comment: A possible work-around: Separate the protobuf files into a separate sub.directory where you build a (static) library. You can then easily use one set of options for the library source files, and one for the main application source files.

Comment: No need for them to be in a different directory, just a separate target will do. If you use an object library then it won't even generate a separate static library

Comment: Command `set_source_files_properties` is the proper way for set per-file compiler flags. Not sure why do you treat is a "HACK" or  "a bit clunky".

Comment: @Tsyvarev because it only takes the flags as a string which seems more old-fashioned.

Answer (score 0):

I found I can use [set_source_files_properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_source_files_properties.html) like this:

```
protobuf_generate_cpp(MYAPP_PROTO_SRCS MYAPP_PROTO_HDRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/myapp.proto)

set(MYAPP_SRCS myapp.cpp)

set_source_files_properties${MYAPP_SRCS} PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS "-Wall;-Werror")

add_executable(myapp ${MYAPP_SRCS} ${MYAPP_PROTO_SRCS})
```